# Frank (cucumber) iOS test element position

Tags: ios, position, cucumber, orientation, frank

I want to test that a UI element repositioned itself after reorientating. The accessability label for the element is "large app icon" and it is a UIImageView. How can I say something like:

```
element("view marked:'large app icon'").frame should_be([ [0,0], [250, 250] ])
```

?